# map list of proteins into an already built network

Tags: bioinformatics, protein-interaction

I have a built reliable network which can be downloaded from here 
http://www.filedropper.com/mynetwork

This network is bulit using Cytoscape. Now I have a list of proteins IDs, for example

```
set1: Q9Y4Y9, P62310, Q9Y4Z0
set2: Q9Y333 ,P62312, O15116
set3: Q9Y4Y9, P62310 
set4: Q9Y4Z0, Q9Y333, O95777, P62312
set5: O14497, P51532, Q8TAQ2, Q92922, P60709, O96019
```

I want to know if it is possible to map the above IDs to the built network? I don't mind using another algorithm, or software , only the result is important

Thanks

Comment: There are markup languages used for describing the network. They have the mapping and the network viewer loads the network file written in the markup language. You have to add more details; as it stands the exact question is a bit unclear.